# Why does the Eclipse Java compiler check casts from null?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, null, bytecode

Consider the following Java snippet:

```
public class Test {
    public static void use(Object[] x) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] x = null;

        use(x);
    }
}
```

The Java bytecode produced for `main()` by the Eclipse 3.7 compiler looks like this:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   aconst_null
   1:   checkcast   #20; //class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
   4:   astore_1
   5:   aload_1
   6:   invokestatic    #21; //Method use:([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   9:   return
```

On the contrary, this is the bytecode produced by the OpenJDK 1.6.0b22 compiler:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   aconst_null
   1:   astore_1
   2:   aload_1
   3:   invokestatic    #2; //Method use:([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   6:   return
```

Note that the Eclipse compiler issues an extra `checkcast` opcode. It also seems to do that only for arrays and not for any other variable type.

My questions:

1. As far as I know, `null` is assignable to any class, including arrays. Does it make *any* sense at all to `checkcast` a known `null` value?
2. Does the extra `checkcast` affect performance?
3. Could this be considered a bug in the Eclipse Java compiler?

NOTE:

I can *partially* answer (2), at least as far as the OpenJDK 1.6.0b22 JVM is concerned. I performed a simple benchmark with several assignments to `null` in a timed tight loop. I could not detect any consistent performance difference, one way or the other.

That said, my benchmark was simple enough that any half-decent optimizer would have probably made it useless, so it may not be indicative of a real world application. I would expect that the JVM would *always* optimize out that `checkcast` opcode, but that may not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your first question, you are right, the checkcast instruction there is redundant.
According to [Sun's Java Hotspot wiki](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques#PerformanceTechniques-Lowlevelsafetychecks) null checks and instance checks are cheap.

I've opened an [issue in Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359284) to get feedback from Eclipse compiler team, but as it been pointed out before, it is redundant, but harmless check. It only affects the bytecode size and Java HotSpot compiler will likely apply type check optimization at the runtime.

Update: [from Eclipse compiler team](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359284#c1) it seem like as side effect of [another old bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26903).

Answer (score 2):

1. No, it doesn't make sense to check, as `null` is always castable to any reference type.  But it doesn't hurt anything.
2. Any decent JIT will optimize the check away anyway (it's effectively a no-op), so the biggest cost is the three bytes that the instruction takes up.
3. I wouldn't consider it a "bug", as the generated bytecode works as intended -- it'll never trigger a `ClassCastException`, as the value is always known and correct -- and, as you apparently saw, there's not a real performance difference either way.  It's an opportunity for improvement, but nothing that will *break* in any case.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to a known bug in javac: [*Unnecessary checkcast in generated code*](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6246854).